# How to post or get into MVC controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem. I have this dropdown list :

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectCountryId, Model.Countries, @Translator.Translate("PLEASE_SELECT"), new { id = "CountryID", @class = "form-control",ng_model="countryId", ng_change = "LoadRegions(countryId);", @required = "required" })
```

And i need on ng_change to get into MVC controller that looks like this:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult GetRegions(int countryId) // return a JsonResult
        {
            IUserManager manager = UserFactory.GetUserManager(WebConfiguration.DefaultTerminalId);
            var model = manager.GetRegions(countryId);
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is script in angular:

```
 $scope.LoadRegions = function (countryId)
    {
        console.log("COUNTRY ID: ", countryId);
        $http.post('/app/Account/GetRegions/'+ countryId).then(function (response)
        {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
```

I get country ID but in console i get this error:

> POST http://localhost:60789/app/Account/GetRegions/4 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Copy that URL in browser and put breakpoint in your `Get Regions` method to determined whether it's called or not!

Comment: i put breakpoint in get regions and it not enters

Comment: That means it doesn''t get called

Comment: ya .. i know but how to call it? when i remove parameters from function then its calld but when i put parameters it say that he parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'countryId' of non-nullable type '

Comment: even if i pass number it say that

Comment: `[HttpPost]` no ? also tits unlikely the url should have `app` in it..

Comment: try change the URL to  : `$http.post('/Account/GetRegions/'` in your Angular call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default routing in MVC allows for `{controller}/{action}/{id}` but your controller is expecting `{controller}/{action}/{countryId}`.

You can change your call to look like:

```
GetRegions?countryId=XXX
```

**Or** change your method signature to look like:

```
public JsonResult GetRegions(int id)
```

Or, if you really want to, you can accommodate this route in your `RouteConfig.cs`

**Edit**: I just realized you're calling this with `$http.post` but everything in your code suggests you want this to be a `GET`, so I'd change your angular code to `$http.get()`

Comment: can i ask u one more question?

Comment: Is it possible that response that i get from angular function populate mvc dropdown list?

Comment: @None, I'm not sure, I've never mixed the two (MVC and Angular) together.  You could definitely populate it with `<select ng-options[...]`

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it there are a few problems in your javascript.

Try the following.

```
$scope.LoadRegions = function (countryId)
    {
        var params = {};
        params.countryId = countryId;

        console.log("COUNTRY ID: ", countryId);
        $http.post('/Account/GetRegions/', params).then(function (response)
        {
            alert(response);
        });
    }
```

As you can see you're passing in the params object with the country ID, you are making a call to the POST on the server side also -> Seperate to the angular `app` folder.